# If $G$ is a simple group of order $60$, how can we there exists some $G\to A_6$ not trivial without using the fact that $G\cong A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

If $G$ is simple, any homomorphism out of $G$ must be trivial or injective since the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup.

If $G$ is simple of order $60$, how can I show that there exists an injective map from $G\to A_6$ without using the fact that $G\cong A_5$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple group $G$ of order $60$ will have six Sylow $5$-subgroups. Then
$G$ acts transitively on them
(by conjugation), so there's a homomorphism $\phi:G\to S_6$
with transitive image. From the simplicity of $G$ it readily follows that
$\phi$ is injective, and $\phi(G)\subseteq A_6$.

Comment: Wonderful solution! I just asked myself why does G have six Sylow 5-subgroups and not just one, and I realised G wouldn't be simple in that case. :)

Comment: How do we know $\phi(G)$ will be contained in $A_6$?

Comment: @AlJebr for otherwise $\phi(G)\xrightarrow{sign}\{\pm 1\}$ would define a normal subgroup of $\phi(G)$.